# How can I get all the child nodes from a parent node in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I'm intending of retrieving a list of nodes from the parent node `societies` which will store the child node names, retrieved from this case being `ALT5` , `ASN11` , `Foot15`

[image: Screenshot of firebase]

The `child` node directly beneath `sUsers` is the `uid` of that user so it can be retrieved using 
`var runUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;` so that the query can work with multiple users with different `child` nodes

EDIT : This needs to work on other nodes within `sUsers` that will have different child nodes under `Societies`

code so far, currently because there are 3 child nodes under `societies` it will log 3 `null` values, whereas I want the actual names of the `child` nodes stored

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
   var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
   var newRoot = rootRef.child(userID).child('Societies')
    newRoot.once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childs){
            var societies = childs.child('Societies').val();
            console.log(societies);

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you posted, the variable `childs` you're using in `DataSnapshot.forEach` is actually each child of the node `'Societies'`.
So this should work:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
    var newRoot = rootRef.child(userID).child('Societies');
    newRoot.once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(_child){
            var society = _child.key;
            console.log(society);
        });
    });
});
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) you can see some documentation and some examples.